# Can't sign in with copilot extension in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2022, enterprise, windows-11, github-copilot

**Visual Studio v .17.8.0; Copilot v 1.133.0.0.**
I have the following exception after installing copilot extension

```
[Error] An error occurred for ‘LSP’: StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. —> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
at StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.<WriteAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<SendAsync>d__157.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__162.MoveNext()
— End of inner exception stack trace —
at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__162.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__1511.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.JsonRpcExtensionMethods.<SendMethodRequestWithTelemetryAsync>d__02.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageClientInstance.<SendInitializeRequestAsync>d__120.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageClientInstance.<InitializeAsync>d__117.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.TplExtensions.<WithTimeout>d__5.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageClientInstance.<TrackTaskAsync>d__118.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client.RemoteLanguageClientInstance.<ActivateLanguageClientAsync>d__127.MoveNext()
Auth Status: NotSignedIn
```

I tried to install Copilot 1.84.0.1 and it worked fine (however it doesn’t have the functionality of the new version that I need). Also, the Copilot extension for Visual Studio Code works fine.

I tried to clean cache, repair, and reinstall the Visual Studio, sign out/sign in GitHub account. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. The problem was with StreamJsonRpc.dll or Newtonsoft.Json.dll in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022[Version]\Common7\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the issue persists you can report an issue to the Visual Studio team via the "report a problem" feature: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report - and hopefully the additional information that tool provides will make it easier to root cause the issue.